# how to find and b piecewise function mathamatica

Tags: piecewise, mathematica-online

how would i find a,b for
[image]

how would i write this in Mathematica to get `a` and `b`

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please look at the documentation for `Piecewise`.

Comment: For example, $a=\pi$ and $b=e$, or any other combination of numbers unless you have some conditions on $a,b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to select `a` and `b` such that the function is piecewise continuous. Then

```
eqns = {
  Limit[(x^2 + 6 x + 5)/(x^2 - 3 x - 4), 
    x -> -1] == (a*x^2 - b*x + 3 /. x -> -1),
  a*x^2 - b*x + 3 == 2 x - a + b /. x -> 3}

(* {-(4/5) == 3 + a + b, 3 + 9 a - 3 b == 6 - a + b} *)

sol = Solve[eqns, {a, b}][[1]]

(* {a -> -(61/70), b -> -(41/14)} *)

f[x_] = Piecewise[{
     {(x^2 + 6 x + 5)/(x^2 - 3 x - 4), x < -1},
     {a*x^2 - b*x + 3, -1 <= x < 3},
     {2 x - a + b, x >= 3}}] /. sol // Simplify
```

[image]

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 4}]
```

[image]